# move_uploaded_file not working?

Tags: php, yii

I want to move a uploaded file in temp folder to new folder... the `oldpath` and `newpath` are correct but the file not moving ... i tried `var_dump` the `move_uploaded_file` and get the result **bool(false)**

**Following is my code:**

```
$theid = Yii::app()->user->getState('id');
$folder = 'developers_apk'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .$theid;

    if(!is_dir($folder)){
        mkdir($folder, 0755);

    }
    if(file_exists($folder)){
        $today = date("Ymd"); 
        $oldpath = Yii::app()->params['tmp_folder'] .$today.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$apkfilename;
        $newpath = 'developers_apk'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .$theid.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$apkfilename;
        move_uploaded_file($oldpath,$newpath);

        if(move_uploaded_file($oldpath,$newpath)){              
            print_r("ok");
        }else{
            var_dump(move_uploaded_file($oldpath,$newpath));
            print_r("NOT"); 
        }
    }else{

        print_r("NOT"); 
    }
```

Did I miss somethings ? Or any suggestion for this ? Thanks

Comment: Could you dump those 2 variables? `var_dump($oldpath);` and `var_dump($newpath);` before the `move_uploaded_file()` call.

Comment: @Glavić `string(75) "C:\xampp\htdocs\dev\open\temp\20141104\5b224412ed04f28c8b2d34320a66321d.apk" string(54) "developers_apk\66\5b224412ed04f28c8b2d34320a66321d.apk"`

Comment: @Glavić the path look correct

Comment: @Glavić i tried using `copy($oldpath,$newpath);` it worked ! but how to delete the temp file ?

Comment: @TheSmile give permission 777 to upload folder

Answer (score 0):

I tried use `copy` then `unlink` it worked ! =)

```
$theid = Yii::app()->user->getState('id');
$folder = 'developers_apk'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .$theid;

    if(!is_dir($folder)){
        mkdir($folder, 0755);
    }

    if(file_exists($folder)){
        $today = date("Ymd"); 
        $apkoldpath = Yii::app()->params['tmp_folder'] .$today.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$apkfilename;
        $apknewpath = 'developers_apk'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .$theid.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$apkfilename;
        copy($apkoldpath,$apknewpath);

        $pngoldpath = Yii::app()->params['tmp_folder'] .$today.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$pngfilename;
        $pngnewpath = 'developers_apk'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .$theid.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$pngfilename;
        copy($pngoldpath,$pngnewpath);

        if(file_exists($apknewpath)){
            unlink($apkoldpath);
        }
        if(file_exists($pngnewpath)){
            unlink($pngoldpath);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `move_uploaded_file()` multiple times, which is incorrect.

Try this:

```
if(file_exists($folder)){
    $today = date("Ymd"); 
    $oldpath = Yii::app()->params['tmp_folder'] .$today.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$apkfilename;
    $newpath = 'developers_apk'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .$theid.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$apkfilename;

    if(move_uploaded_file($oldpath,$newpath)){              
        print_r("ok");
    }else{
        print_r("NOT"); 
    }
}else{
    print_r("NOT"); 
}
```

Comment: thanks your answer ... i tried result is **NOT** ... I tried use copy then unlink it worked ! ...